# Is it possible for integrals to have functions of the integrand in the bounds of the integral such as $\int_0^x xdx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

Is it possible for integrals to have functions of the integrand in the bounds of the integral such as $\int_0^x x\,dx$ or more generally $\int_0^{f(x)} x\,dx$ ?

I have seen this several times in the past few weeks for the first time and I am not sure whether they were typos. If this is possible, would the solution be :

$$\left. \frac {x^2} 2 \right|^x_0 \text{ ?}$$

Comment: People sometimes write things like $\displaystyle \int_0^x \cos x\,dx$ when they are in effect treating the $x$ in $\displaystyle \int_0^x$ and the $x$ in $\cos x\,dx$ as two different things. It is at best infelicitous notation and I avoid it. $\qquad$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533541/integral-notation-confusion-x-vs-t?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The variable of integration is a loop variable and it goes out of scope before the endpoints get evaluated.

Comment: I live in two worlds. Scope of variables should be taught to mathematicians.

Comment: Are you saying no to the first question of the possibility of evaluation or to the proposed solution?

Comment: It simply makes no sense.

Comment: It's sometimes used as bad notation - the variable of integration should be a dummy variable that doesn't appear outside the integral term.